# How to wrap div around image?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I trying to wrap image inside a div, but the div gets expanded by the parent div.

```
<div id="parent" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align:center">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img>
    </div>
    <p>Some text that expands the wrapper div more than image width</p>
</div>
```

The text field expands the parent div to be wider than the image and this also expands the wrapper div. How can I make the wrapper div to be exactly the same size as the img?

img nor the wrapper have no margin or padding, but yet wrapper div is wider than the image.

Comment: do you have any other css?

Comment: `div`s are block elements so they will take up the full width of their parent. try setting `wrapper` to `display:inline` or `float:left`, depending how you want it to show.

Comment: @Firze put the display: inline-block on the #wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` on #wrappper

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dccyy47r/)

Comment: Oh. I was quite sure I already tried it but obviously I didn't. Thanks. I feel dumb now.

Comment: @Firze I like adding borders to the elements so I can see exactly what is happening. Hope you'll try my method. :)

Comment: If `display: inline-block` doesn't work, try with `display: inline`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `display:inline-block` on wraper element

```
 <div id="parent" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align:center">
    <div id="wrapper" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/source_code-128.png" />        
    </div>    
    <p>Some text that expands the wrapper div more than image width</p>
</div>
```

If you want to keep `p` size same as image you need use some JavaScript or jQuery

e.g.

```
 $('#parent').css({
     maxWidth: $('img').width()
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7p9rv8q/)**